# Django: Manually getting the view corresponding to a URL

Tags: python, django, url

I have a Django project. Given a url, how can I know which view will be dispatched to handle the request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `django.core.urlresolvers.resolve`, which allows you to map an URL to a view and to keep your URL & view logic separate.  This is the opposite of `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` which allows you to map a view to a URL.

See the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve) for how to use it!